# How to pass value from textBox from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have:

```
@model DataAccess.AdeccoView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AdeccoView</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "EmployeeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.ClientName, "ClientName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.ClientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @*@Html.EditorForModel(model => model.Client.ClientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }))*@

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.ClientName, "upisi me!", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VisitTypeID, "VisitTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("VisitTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VisitTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResultTypeID, "ResultTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ResultTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResultTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

For `EditorFor` helper, I want to pass through POST method in my controller `ClientName`.

Firstly, in the GET method, I've tried to make a new `ViewBag` or to call through new instance.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Client = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientName");//I've added this
    ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName");
    return View();
}
```

Next, in my POST method I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ViewID,EmployeeID,Date,VisitTypeID,ResultTypeID,ClientName, ClientID")] AdeccoView adeccoView)
{
    Client client = new Client();
    AdeccoView view = new AdeccoView();
    string a = view.Client.ClientName;//here is my code throw an error

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.AdeccoView.Add(adeccoView);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Klijent = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientName");
    ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName", adeccoView.ClientID);
    ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employee, "EmployeeD", "Name", adeccoView.EmployeeID);
    ViewBag.ResultTypeID = new SelectList(db.ResultType, "ResultTypeID", "ResultName", adeccoView.ResultTypeID);
    ViewBag.VisitTypeID = new SelectList(db.VisitType, "VisitTypeID", "VisitTypeName", adeccoView.VisitTypeID);
    return View(adeccoView);
}
```

Maybe it is a difference will I put `EditorFor`, `EditorForModel` or `TextBox`? 
Thanks.

edit: with `TextBox` helper, I've managed to pass it through `Request.Form[]` in a post method, but css now is a tricky one.

Comment: You awful `[Bind]` attribute is excluding property `Client` from binding. But you never even access it anyway so its unclear what you think your doing. There are so many errors in your code its hard to know where to start. But you error is thrown because you initialize a new instance of `AdeccoView` in your POST method and then access the `Client.ClientName` but `Client` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

there is no different between editorFor and textbox. the only important things here is the name.
you use client.ClientName but you declare in your action input just ClientName
I hope you get the whole Idea

Comment: I fixed it. I declared @Html.TextBox ("ClientName","") and then, I put Request.Form["ClientName"], so it is unnecessary to call ti from my awful [Bind] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a flat view model for your view and use that for transferring data between your view and your action method. You may add properties to store the data for your drop down so that we can avoid dynamic stuff like `ViewBag`.

```
public class CreateAdeccoView
{
   public int EmployeeID {set;get;}
   public int ClientID  {set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Employees {set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItme> Clients {set;get;}
   public DateTime CreateDate {set;get;}
   //Add other properties as needed

}
```

and in your GET action, you create an object of this, load the collection properties and send to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateAdeccoView();
  vm.Clients = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName");
  vm.Employees = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");

  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view

```
@model CreateAdecooView
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Employee </label>
  @Html.DropDownListfor(s=>s.EmployeeID,Model.Employees,"Select one")

  <label>Client</label>
  @Html.DropDownListfor(s=>s.ClientID,Model.Clients ,"Select one")

  <label>Date </label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.CreateDate)

  <input type="submit"/ >
}
```

And in your HttpPost action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateAdeccoView model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      AdeccoView view = new AdeccoView();
      view.EmployeeId=model.EmployeeID;
      view.ClientID=model.ClientID;
      //Don't forget to map other properties as well.

     db.AdeccoView.Add(adeccoView);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");

  }   
  //Reload the data for dropdown again    
  model.Clients = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientID", "ClientName");
  model.Employees = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju! I will try it out!